# Wifi dongle speed is slower than advertised

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, kubuntu

I would like to start off by saying I am new to linux (been about 2-3 weeks). I purchased a [Maxesla Mini WiFi Adapter 1200M 802.11ac Dual Band 2.4/5GHz AC1200 Wireless Network Adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07P7JQVKB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) usb dongle and installed the [rtl88x2bu driver updated for current kernels](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959) driver (I followed the DKMS installation).

I get the full 450-500mbps speeds when using an ethernet cable on my laptop (or wifi on my cell phone), but about 200 mbps when using this dongle. I am using Kubuntu 18.4 LTS and the build-in wifi (2.4g) is enabled as I don't know how to disable it (don't know if that makes a difference).

Thank you in advance!

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 01
       serial: 18:cf:5e:35:79:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.18.0-22-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:39 memory:f0c00000-f0c7ffff memory:f0c80000-f0c8ffff   *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: c4:54:44:98:86:bf
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff   *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1.1
       logical name: wlx1cbfce387297
       serial: 1c:bf:ce:38:72:97
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88x2bu ip=192.168.0.159 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. touchpad
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
4: phy2: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**EDIT 1:
iwconfig**

```
wlx1cbfce387297  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"Shabana_BETTER"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: B8:EC:A3:31:29:71   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=78/100  Signal level=53/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: Note that you bought the item from _Amazon Marketplace_, not Amazon proper, which means it's basically an unknown seller sending you _something_ from an unknown country (see also [this SE answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/166904/51515)). Some extra clues: claiming 1200Mbps since "5GHz/867Mbps+2.4G/300Mbps" (I'm pretty sure you can't use those in parallel), and sketchy English such as "[we] offer the [sic] fast response".

Comment: Didn't even know there were different amazons hehe

Comment: I currently have a rtl8821CU connected on two computers. One computer I get 20MB/s while the other computer only gets 2MB/s both on 5.8GHz connection (802.11AC). I have moved both WiFi dongles to the different USB ports on the MOBO and get the same results derived for the same MOBO. Frustrating altogether that the performance difference between MOBO are drastic enough to see a significant performance difference to the same WiFi dongle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I get the full 450-500mbps speeds when using an ethernet cable on my laptop (or wifi on my cell phone), but about 200 mbps when using this dongle.

It has a ***tiny*** antenna, which gives it very poor reception. It has a cheap chipset. I'm actually *surprised* that you get this good speeds from this.

Furthermore, it does not mention USB3, which makes me suspect it's USB2. USB2 maxes out at 480Mb/s, in practice I've noticed gigabit NIC's connected to USB2 ports tends to give around 200-250Mb/s.

So in short. You're getting way better speed than I would expect. You will probably not get any more out of that device. Get one with USB3 and a better antenna.

In addition wireless gives approximately half of advertised rate at best. When my NIC announces 867Mb/s, I get around 450Mb/s under good conditions. This is a Intel 7265 on PCIe.

Comment: Yeah I put the dongle right next to the modem and got speeds up to 380 :) I guess I'll have to spend more when I'll need that much speed